# Is it possible to flush log4j2 messages to console immediately while debugging?

Tags: java, debugging, log4j2

During debugging I want to get log messages immediately. I thought there is something like BufferSize for Console appender:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" > 
        <BufferSize>2</BufferSize>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
```

however, it seems not to be supported. Is there any solution to get messages immediately?

Comment: A good deal of appenders have an `immediateFlush` property. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html That said, if your breakpoint is stopping the world, you might still block the thread that's midway through a write. You could change your breakpoint to only stop the thread that it occurred on, which would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I haven't found any solution up till now I opened an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3106)